# Psd to html but style not applying

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I am learning psd to html and starting from scratch but I cannot get a div to apply my style.

I have the following for my div in styles.css

```
div header header-text
{
    top:25px;
    left:54px;
    font-size:30pt
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;    
}
```

This is my html

```
<html>
<head>      
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>        
<body>
    <div class="header">
       <div class=header-text">100+ Years Of Combiend Expierence</div>
       <div class="header-logo"></div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Are there any good plugins out their that would get the bare bones style sheet setup.

Comment: Just update your selector: `div.header .header-text`. Remove the space between `div` & `.header`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

Your [selectors](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) are wrong. The correct selectors would be:

```
div.header .header-text
```

or forgo the 1st div element selector completely, and just have:

```
.header .header-text
```

---

**Some more context on the subject:**

In the example above:
`div` is an element selector & `.header` `.header-text` are class selectors.

The common selector types you'll most likely encounter (but not limited to) are:

> - `ELEMENT` - Where it'll just the the html element tag name such as
>     `div, span, body`
>
>   - Just know that whatever you apply to this
>       selector will apply to **ALL** elements of that type (if you don't
>       have sub selectors increasing the [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/))
> - `CLASS` -  Where it'll be a (any name you decide upon) name
>     pre-pended with a dot
>
>   - E.g. `.header-text`, `.myFancyClass`
> - `ID` -   Where it'll be a (any name you decide upon) name
>     pre-pended with a hash
>
>   - E.g. `#some-id`, `#foo`

**Also...**

In CSS the spacing between your classes/selectors matter. Thus in your html:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="header-text">100+ Years Of Combiend Expierence</div>
        <div class="header-logo"></div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

1. The `header` class is on the top `div`, thus you'd need `div.header` to target it.
2. Then, `header-text` in a child element. Thus you'd need a space, then the class name (or whatever child selector), resulting in a final selector combo/group of `div.header .header-text`.
3. If you want to go even deeper, add another space and another child selector.

To visualize the above:

```
div.header                // same element
  .header-text            // child
      .header-logo        // child of child

----------------------------------------------

// same elem  |child       |child of child
   div.header .header-text .header-logo
```

Have a look at this [CSS cheat sheet](http://www.cheetyr.com/css-selectors) to see what other options you have available at you disposal, also read up on CSS [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) to make sense of it all.

Comment: I tried that but its still not applying dont no why

Comment: sorry i had a typo, the main class header, needs to touch the div selector.
`div.header .header-text`. I'm busy updating my answer to explain the correct usage

Comment: that worked how would i also select header-logo just need to get the basics over me then ill be ok

Comment: You can do any combo. If you only want to target `header-text`  if its within `header` then do this `.header .header-text`, if you have lots of header-text's, that need to look the same, but they dont need to be within header-text. then just do this `.header-text`

Comment: @David its all about specificity. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: dear you forgot the quotation for `<div class=header-text>`  it should be `<div class="header-text">`

Comment: @AlaaMh thanks dear (though, originally it was copied from the question as is)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about the [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). If you want to select an item by class, put it.

```css
.header-text{
    top:25px;
    left:54px;
    font-size:30pt
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">
      <div class=header-text>100+ Years Of Combiend Expierence</div>

          <div class="header-logo"></div>                   

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use apply written CSS for classes, therefore you must use . (dot) before html tags and not space between div and header class:

div.header .header-text